# Can I step through all the javascript a browser is parsing without setting breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any method to step through **all** the javascript a browser is parsing, without having to manually set breakpoints? I'm looking for a simple "step through javascript" switch that would in essence put a breakpoint at every single line in every javascript file a site is using, so that I can closely follow the entire trail of code the browser parses, at my leisure.

For the record I'm specifically looking to do this for events, eg a click event that triggers a whole cascade of javascript-driven changes to a site.

Comment: https://puu.sh/y9rXn/16e7bfda0b.png, load the page, and then press F10 or F11 key.

Comment: Yes, just set a breakpoint on every event. Not in the code. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for Chrome, I couldn't find the equivalent functionality in Firefox.

- Load the page
- Open developer tools
- Click on sources panel
- On the bottom of the right pane, expand Event Listener Breakpoints
- Under "Script" header, check Script First Statement
- Reload the page
- Press F9 or the icon in the upper right of sources panel that is an arrow pointing at a circle, aka "Step"

This will allow you to manually step through literally all the javascript the browser is parsing, from start to finish. Note that this will also pause on the first line of any js used by browser extensions as well.